# I want to put a number on the panel of my application

Tags: html, css

[image]

i have an application where i have to implement a sliding panel and  add a picture on that panel i have implemnted that panel, but i can not add picture to that position i mentioned in the picture.This is my code without css and js.

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper"> 
  <div id="content">  
      <div class="demo">
        <h2 align="center">DASHBOARD</h2>

  <div> <h3 class="expand"><p>STPCODE NOT REGISTERED</p></h3>         
        <div class="collapse">
            <p>List of unregistered user are here</p>
        </div>         

         </div>      
        <h3 class="expand"><p>TOTAL NUMBER OF REGISTERED USER IN DRAFT MODE</p></h3>
        <div class="collapse">
            <p>List of  user in draft mode are here</p>
        </div>
        <h3 class="expand"><p>TOTAL NUMBER OF PAYMENT INITIATED</p></h3>
        <div class="collapse">
            <p>Total number of users who have their payment initiated</p>
        </div>
        <h3 class="expand"><p>TOTAL NUMBER OF PAYMENT RECIEVED</p></h3>
        <div class="collapse">
            <p>Total number of users who have their payment Recived</p>
        </div>
        <h3 class="expand"><p>TOTAL NUMBER OF PAYMENT DISAPPROVED</p></h3>
        <div class="collapse">
            <p>Total number of users who have their payment disapproved</p>
        </div>
      </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to add picture in the position i added in the picture.plese help

Answer (score 0):

Imo you should make a bit more of reasearch before asking something so basic but anyway here you have this as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8knmd7pd/

It's just basic use of:

```
background-image: url();
```

In the jsfiddle the image will be positiones at the right of your "h3"... if you want to give an specific location use px like, for example:

```
background-position: center 200px;
```